# convert webform date to oracle format

Tags: 6, webforms, datetime

I need to ask some help in converting the date format of a webform.

I'm writing a custom module that send the submissions of my webforms to a third party, however I have to convert my date format from "m/d/Y - H:i a" to the oracle format "DD-MON-YYYY"

I've read up on articles saying that webform uses the site's "short form" but Ideally I'd like to make the conversion in my mod, to keep it contained and because I don't know if changing the "short form" will break anything currently on the site.

This is the line capturing the date field of my form:

```
 $dob = $submission->data[11]['value'][0];
```

I'm using Drupal 6.19 and webforms 6.x-3.4
if anyone can give me some suggestions I'd appreciate it.
Please let me know if I need to provide more detail.

Thanks!
Steph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a PHP question, I believe, as you use PHP functions to accomplish this.

```
<?php   
  $dob = $submission->data[11]['value'][0];
  $time = strtotime($dob);
  $oracle_format = date('d-m-Y', $time);
  // OR
  // $oracle_format = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dob));
?>
```

This uses the functions [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: You are right, it's a PHP question. But I need to ask more help - I just attempted $dob = date('m/d/Y - H:ia'); to test your code and it failed (wsod). I'm really stumped so any additional help is very welcome!

Comment: I just edited the question, I had the arguments for `date()` transposed. Re: your test: that code shouldn't fail.  You should turn on debugging `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` or check the logs to see what else is going on.

Comment: thanks again for more help, I'm getting an interesting result. $date = date('m/d/Y - H:ia');
$oracle_format = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date));
echo $oracle_format;

gives me back the date 31-Dec-1969 rather than today's date.
any ideas?

Comment: So this is an issue that `strtotime()` can't convert your format.  Can you add an actual value that `$submission->data[11]['value'][0];` contains?

Comment: yes, I've tried his with the same result - $date = date('07/10/2013 - 14:50pm');
$oracle_format = date('d-M-Y', strtotime($date)); I still get 31-Dec-1969

Comment: is there a way to utilize "now" as the optional pram? I've been looking for examples but it doesn't seem to be well documented

Comment: Optional param for what?

Comment: the strtotime has an optional param of "now", http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php. I id end up getting this working by just using "now", and it shows the correct date, but not when I use the submitted info.

Comment: I think I may have it, would you mind testing: $date_string = "07/10/2013 - 17:31pm";
$date_exploded = explode('-',$date_string);

$date = strtotime($date_exploded[0]);
$date = date('d-M-Y', $date);
echo $date;

Comment: I may not have used your example exactly, but you got my thinking the right way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with your time string of "07/10/2013 14:50pm"
You are mixing 24hr format with AM/PM, which confuses the parser.

Either use date('H:i') [14:50] or date('g:ia') [2:50pm]

Comment: The " - " in the string also messes things up, apparently.

Comment: Right, but I can't do anything about that "-", do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to use a preg_replace to remove the date info? since I'm only looking for d-m-Y. and how might I do that?

Comment: I think I may have it, if you wouldn't mine trying this? the static value for $date_string will be the dynamic submitted value:  $date_string = "07/10/2013 - 17:31pm";
$date_exploded = explode('-',$date_string);

$date = strtotime($date_exploded[0]);
$date = date('d-M-Y', $date);
echo $date;